# How to sell software that is uploaded via snap

Tags: application-development, snap, commercial

In the FAQ it says that one is able to sell commercial software in the Ubuntu Software Center. I have already uploaded my software via snap and I wonder where I may enter a price.

Comment: Who is running the Ubuntu Software Center? Nobody is able to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in selling apps in the snap store.

We're in the final stages of enabling purchasing within the snap store. Once that's ready we'll announce it publicly, but for now, while we perform our final validation and ensure there are no issues with the process, it's disabled.

Comment: Any ETA on this?